# Output of doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list

I've been attempting to make a doubly linked list (I feel like I'm so close), but I just can't seem to get the right output. My output seems to throw some really random values at me. I feel like the problem is due to my operator overloading but I just can't seem to fathom it out and the morning sun approaches XD. Thank you all very much for any help!

Also for convenience, expected output is: (ignore spaces between lines)

Prince Massi

Joel David Conrad Prince Massi

Nic Lindo Ernest Joel David Conrad Prince Massi

Nic Lindo Ernest Joel David Conrad Prince Massi

Lindo Ernest Joel David Conrad Prince Massi

Lindo Ernest Joel David Conrad Pince Massi Jesse Shane Richard

Lindo Ernest Joel David Conrad Pince Massi Jesse Shane

Lindo Ernest Joel David Conrad Pince Massi Jesse

Lindo Ernest Joel David Conrad Pince Massi

Lindo Ernest Joel David Conrad Pince

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class StringNode{
    public:
        string elem;
        StringNode* next;
        StringNode* prev;
        friend class StringLinkedList;
};

class StringLinkedList{
    public:
        StringLinkedList();
        ~StringLinkedList();
        bool isEmpty() const;
        const string& front() const;
        const string& back() const;
        void addFront(const string& e);
        void addBack(const string& e);
        void removeFront();
        void removeBack();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const StringLinkedList& obj);
    private:
        StringNode* head;
        StringNode* tail;
    protected:
        void add(StringNode* v, const string& e);
        void remove(StringNode* v);
};

StringLinkedList::StringLinkedList(){
    head = new StringNode;
    tail = new StringNode;
    head->next = tail;
    tail->prev = head;
}

StringLinkedList::~StringLinkedList(){
    while(!isEmpty()){
        removeFront();
    }
    delete head;
    delete tail;
}

bool StringLinkedList::isEmpty() const{
    return (head->next == tail);
}

const string& StringLinkedList::front() const{
    return head->next->elem;
}

const string& StringLinkedList::back() const{
    return tail->prev->elem;
}

void StringLinkedList::add(StringNode* v, const string& e){
    StringNode* u = new StringNode; u->elem = e;
    u->next = v;
    u->prev = v->prev;
    v->prev->next = v->prev = u;
}

void StringLinkedList::addFront(const string& e){
    add(head->next, e);
}

void StringLinkedList::addBack(const string& e){
    add(tail, e);
}

void StringLinkedList::remove(StringNode* v){
    StringNode* u = v->prev;
    StringNode* w = v->next;
    u->next = w;
    w->prev = u;
    delete v;
}

void StringLinkedList::removeFront(){
    remove(head->next);
}

void StringLinkedList::removeBack(){
    remove(tail->prev);
}

ostream& operator <<( ostream& out, const StringLinkedList &obj )
{
    for ( StringNode *temp = obj.head->next; temp != obj.tail; temp = temp->next )
    {
        out << temp->elem << ' ';
    }
    return out;
}

int main(void){
    StringLinkedList* myList = new StringLinkedList();
    myList->addFront("Massi");
    myList->addFront("Prince");
    cout<< *myList << endl;
    myList->addFront("Conrad");
    myList->addFront("David");
    myList->addFront("Joel");
    cout<< *myList << endl;
    myList->addFront("Ernest");
    myList->addFront("Lindo");
    myList->addFront("Nic");
    cout<< *myList << endl;
    myList->addFront("Sasha");
    myList->removeFront();
    cout<< *myList << endl;
    myList->removeFront();
    cout<< *myList << endl;
    myList ->addBack("Jesse");
    myList ->addBack("Shane");
    myList ->addBack("Richard");
    cout << *myList << endl;
    myList -> removeBack ();
    cout << *myList << endl;
    myList -> removeBack ();
    cout << *myList << endl;
    myList -> removeBack ();
    cout << *myList << endl;
    myList -> removeBack ();
    cout << *myList << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out the "Law of Three", which will surely bite you. Further, don't use new unless you have to, like e.g. for `myList` in `main()`.

Comment: What is your *actual* output?

Comment: Prince Massi  á&Q ─ Q       6 N  Nc2  á&Q ─ Q g 7, 
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.350 s

Comment: As you can see, the first line outputs correctly, the rest goes haywire :/

Comment: first of all I don't like that you create two nodes and then assign them to point to each other. it is better to create a node once it is added then set the pointers. the first element in the double list would have prev = nullptr and the last next == nullptr.

Comment: I was wondering about that.. Oddly enough that bit of code I used was actually from our textbook (who can you trust these days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operator

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const StringLinkedList& obj){
    StringNode* temp = obj.head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        out << temp->elem << ' ';
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return out;
}
```

is wrong because it tries to output data member `elem` of `head` that does not store a string and of `tail` that also does not store a string and moreover has uninitialized member `next`.

The function could be defined the following way

```
ostream& operator <<( ostream& out, const StringLinkedList &obj )
{
    for ( StringNode *temp = obj.head->next; temp != obj.tail; temp = temp->next )
    {
        out << temp->elem << ' ';
    }

    return out;
}
```

Also the last statement of function add is wrong

```
v->prev->next = v->prev = u;
```

You should split it in two statements. For example

```
void StringLinkedList::add( StringNode *v, const string &e )
{
    StringNode *u = new StringNode; u->elem = e;
    u->next = v;
    u->prev = v->prev;
    u->prev->next = u;
    v->prev = u;
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you :D However "tail" would be not be declared in this scope? (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: @Jared It is a data member of class StringLinkedList and the operator is a friend function. So it has access to this data member.

Comment: Thats what I thought but it's giving me that error which is a bit peculiar :/

Comment: @Jared Oh, there is a typo. There must be obj.tail

Comment: I'm clearly tired for not spotting that! Thank you so much for all your help! It's much appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Assume `u` is in sequence.

The code below

```
void StringLinkedList::add(StringNode* v, const string& e){
StringNode* u = new StringNode; u->elem = e;
u->next = v;
u->prev = v->prev;
v->prev->next = v->prev = u; // this line has the issue
```

}

performs the following process (assume 1 = head, 2 = v, 3 = tail)

Let's add "4" in between v = 2 and tail = 3, that is, perform add(tail, data).

u = 4;
4's next is tail
4's previous is tail (3)'s current previous, which is 2
Now we modify the original list's backwards links. Then 3's previous is 4, but then 4 (which is v->prev now)'s next is 4, which is itself.

It really helps to walk through the code, line by line. Use a rubber duck:

[image]

Comment: I understand how that doesn't make sense, but I'm absolutely baffled as to how I could rewrite that code to do what I need :( (sorry for being such a noob it seems)